# How can I get different rows into tables from a CSV file?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i want to get row 1, of my csv upload file into table tab1........ and row 2, into table tab2

i have tried:

```
$myid = 231;
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if ($row == 1) {
                $row++;
                continue;
            }
            $row++;
            foreach (['tab1', 'tab2'] as $table) {
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE $table SET fname=?, lname=? WHERE id=?");
                $stmt->execute([$data[0], $data[1], $myid]);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work in your code? Do you get an error? Have you tried printing your created statement? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, , the error is that both table gets only the last file of the csv

Comment: The last row rather.

Comment: After `if ($row == 1) ....` $row is incrementent, on next loop it is incremented again, is this what you think it should do?

Comment: yes, and each time only one row should be inserted @Luuk

Comment: Still unclear, how do you want to insert a row using `UPDATE ....` ?

Comment: Yes,ignore header row, insert first row into table one using update query where myid is 231 and insert second row into table two  using update query where myid is 231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would be because your foreach loop to insert into the tables inserts into both tables every time around the while loop. You only want to insert tab1 if $row==1 and tab2 is $row==2. Try this (untested):

```
$myid = 231;
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = 0;
        $tables = ['tab1', 'tab2'];

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE && $row<3) {
            if ($row > 0) {
              $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ".$tables[$row-1]." SET fname=?, lname=? WHERE id=?");
              $stmt->execute([$data[0], $data[1], $myid]);
            }
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

I create an array of the 2 tables and then update the relevant table based on the row number.

I have also added a break when we get to 2 rows just incase the CSV has more rows than you are expecting.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly... thanks... but what if i have more tables?, will this still work if i added a table to the table array?

Comment: Assuming you mean that row 3 would go into table 3 then yes, add the table to the array and change the while loop to $row<4